# See "Got status: &{NOT_FOUND}" in first-network from CLI

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When I run into fabric-samples/first-network,

```
./byfn.sh up
```

From the CLI, during

```
Creating channel...
+ peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:......
```

I saw something like

```
[cli/common] readBlock -> INFO 051 Got status: &{NOT_FOUND}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

The Log is..

```
./byfn.sh up
Starting for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] 
proceeding ...
LOCAL_VERSION=1.2.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.2.0
/home/will/Documents/blockchain/fabric-samples/first-network/../bin/cryptogen

##########################################################
##### Generate certificates using cryptogen tool #########
##########################################################
+ cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
org1.example.com
org2.example.com
+ res=0
+ set +x

/home/will/Documents/blockchain/fabric-samples/first-network/../bin/configtxgen
##########################################################
#########  Generating Orderer Genesis block ##############
##########################################################
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
2018-08-02 17:43:52.167 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> WARN 001 Omitting the channel ID for configtxgen is deprecated.  Explicitly passing the channel ID will be required in the future, defaulting to 'testchainid'.
2018-08-02 17:43:52.167 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 002 Loading configuration
2018-08-02 17:43:52.173 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewChannelGroup -> WARN 003 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the channel group in configtx.yaml
2018-08-02 17:43:52.173 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewOrdererGroup -> WARN 004 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the orderer group in configtx.yaml
2018-08-02 17:43:52.174 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewOrdererOrgGroup -> WARN 005 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the orderer org group OrdererOrg in configtx.yaml
2018-08-02 17:43:52.174 CST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 006 Loading NodeOUs
2018-08-02 17:43:52.174 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewOrdererOrgGroup -> WARN 007 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the orderer org group Org1MSP in configtx.yaml
2018-08-02 17:43:52.174 CST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 008 Loading NodeOUs
2018-08-02 17:43:52.174 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewOrdererOrgGroup -> WARN 009 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the orderer org group Org2MSP in configtx.yaml
2018-08-02 17:43:52.174 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 00a Generating genesis block
2018-08-02 17:43:52.174 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 00b Writing genesis block
+ res=0
+ set +x

#################################################################
### Generating channel configuration transaction 'channel.tx' ###
#################################################################
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID mychannel
2018-08-02 17:43:52.202 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2018-08-02 17:43:52.210 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputChannelCreateTx -> INFO 002 Generating new channel configtx
2018-08-02 17:43:52.210 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewApplicationGroup -> WARN 003 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the application group in configtx.yaml
2018-08-02 17:43:52.210 CST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 004 Loading NodeOUs
2018-08-02 17:43:52.210 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewApplicationOrgGroup -> WARN 005 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the application org group Org1MSP in configtx.yaml
2018-08-02 17:43:52.211 CST [msp] getMspConfig -> INFO 006 Loading NodeOUs
2018-08-02 17:43:52.211 CST [common/tools/configtxgen/encoder] NewApplicationOrgGroup -> WARN 007 Default policy emission is deprecated, please include policy specificiations for the application org group Org2MSP in configtx.yaml
2018-08-02 17:43:52.212 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputChannelCreateTx -> INFO 008 Writing new channel tx
+ res=0
+ set +x

#################################################################
#######    Generating anchor peer update for Org1MSP   ##########
#################################################################
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel -asOrg Org1MSP
2018-08-02 17:43:52.244 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2018-08-02 17:43:52.250 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputAnchorPeersUpdate -> INFO 002 Generating anchor peer update
2018-08-02 17:43:52.250 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputAnchorPeersUpdate -> INFO 003 Writing anchor peer update
+ res=0
+ set +x

#################################################################
#######    Generating anchor peer update for Org2MSP   ##########
#################################################################
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID mychannel -asOrg Org2MSP
2018-08-02 17:43:52.280 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2018-08-02 17:43:52.285 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputAnchorPeersUpdate -> INFO 002 Generating anchor peer update
2018-08-02 17:43:52.285 CST [common/tools/configtxgen] doOutputAnchorPeersUpdate -> INFO 003 Writing anchor peer update
+ res=0
+ set +x

Creating network "net_byfn" with the default driver
Creating volume "net_orderer.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org1.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer1.org1.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org2.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer1.org2.example.com" with default driver
Creating orderer.example.com    ... done
Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Creating peer1.org1.example.com ... done
Creating peer1.org2.example.com ... done
Creating cli                    ... done

 ____    _____      _      ____    _____ 
/ ___|  |_   _|    / \    |  _ \  |_   _|
\___ \    | |     / _ \   | |_) |   | |  
 ___) |   | |    / ___ \  |  _ <    | |  
|____/    |_|   /_/   \_\ |_| \_\   |_|  

Build your first network (BYFN) end-to-end test

Channel name : mychannel
Creating channel...
+ peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
+ res=0
+ set +x
2018-08-02 09:44:06.917 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-08-02 09:44:06.936 UTC [cli/common] readBlock -> INFO 002 Got status: &{NOT_FOUND}
2018-08-02 09:44:06.939 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-08-02 09:44:07.141 UTC [cli/common] readBlock -> INFO 004 Received block: 0
===================== Channel 'mychannel' created ===================== 

Having all peers join the channel...
+ peer channel join -b mychannel.block
+ res=0
+ set +x
2018-08-02 09:44:07.195 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-08-02 09:44:07.684 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 002 Successfully submitted proposal to join channel
===================== peer0.org1 joined channel 'mychannel' =====================
```

You may search "&{NOT_FOUND}" from the log........

Comment: We need more context to answer your question. Maybe you can post a gist of your log output? Can you also describe whether or not you had previously run the tutorial?

Comment: Hey @christo4ferris, I am running the demo from https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html, acutally no exception throw during the tutorial (with Release 1.2.0), I just saw this information from the CLI log.

Comment: Ah ok, that could be a bug...

Answer (score 0):

in our case, the channel name, id were wrong

Running docker tail immediately after starting up docker-compose showed the errors

```
docker logs -f orderer.coupons.com
docker logs -f cli
```

panic: Error creating channelconfig bundle: initializing configtx manager failed: bad channel ID: channel ID 'custom_channel' contains illegal characters

And always pass/export CHANNEL_NAME for each command